# determining whether two matrices are row equivalent without any calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a simple theorem that actually states that given two arbitrary matrices, one can determine whether the two matrices are row equivalent?

Comment: What does 'row equivalent' mean?

Comment: _Without any calculation_ is a pretty strong restriction.

Comment: @copper.hat
or 'row-equivalence'. Two matrices A and B are row equivalence if and only if matrix A can be 'transformed' into matrix B, and vice versa, via elementary row operation.

Comment: Determinants can be transfirmed not matrices

Comment: Two matrices are row equivalent if and only if they have the same reduced row echelon form.  Computing the two reduced row echelon forms amounts to constructing a sequence of elementary row operations that transforms one matrix into the other (that goes via the RREF).  In this sense, it's a constructive method.  I guess the between-the-lines question is: is there a non-constructive method?